# Write a function that asks the user to enter their name, age and height in meters and then display a customised message using a single print statement

Tags: jython, jes

```
name = requestString("Enter your name:")

age = requestNumber("Enter your age:")

height = requestNumber("Enter your height:")

print "Hello", name, "!", "i see that you are", num, "years old", "&", height, "tall"
```

Its not printing as i want it to print.

Comment: what result it print

Comment: nothing, konjum help panunge bro

Comment: There is no num variable declared. So change num to age in print code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no num vaiable declared.

use age instead of num in

> print "Hello", name, "!", "i see that you are", ***num***, "years
>   old", "&", height, "tall"

Use

```
print "Hello", name, "!", "i see that you are", age, "years old", "&", height, "tall"
```